# How do you Figure out if any of the buttons was clicked in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe program, and want to know how I figure out if any of the buttons was clicked and which button it was. I am currently repeating the code inside every button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Visible = false;
  label1.Text = "X";
  Application.DoEvents();

}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button2.Visible = false;
  label2.Text = "X";
  Application.DoEvents();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button3.Visible = false;
   label3.Text = "X"
   Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: WinForms?  ASP.NET? MVC?  WPF?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: windows application form in c#

Comment: @ShaltielShmidman: If you have multiple buttons, I would suggest to use dynamically creating buttons using `panel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ForEach(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways to accomplish what you're after (assuming WinForms)..

First, you could wire up all buttons to point to the same event handler.. and check its name:

```
// In the form designer code:
this.buttonNW.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
this.buttonN.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
this.buttonNE.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);


// in the form code:
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Button thisButton = (Button)sender;

    switch (thisButton.Name) {
        case "buttonNW":
            MessageBox.Show("North West button clicked");
            break;
        case "buttonN":
            MessageBox.Show("Northern button clicked");
            break;
        case "buttonNE":
            MessageBox.Show("North East button clicked");
            break;
    }
}
```

Secondly, you could just put the logic into it's own function and call that function for each individual event handler:

```
private void buttonNW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    handleButtonClick("buttonNW");
}

private void buttonN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    handleButtonClick("buttonN");
}

private void buttonNE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    handleButtonClick("buttonNE");
}

private void handleButtonClick(string buttonName) {
    switch (buttonName) {
        case "buttonNW":
            MessageBox.Show("North West button clicked");
            break;
        case "buttonN":
            MessageBox.Show("Northern button clicked");
            break;
        case "buttonNE":
            MessageBox.Show("North East button clicked");
            break;
    }
}
```

I would personally go with option 2 so that everything is clear.

It's a trivial exercise though, considering you'll only ever have a maximum of 9 buttons in a tic-tac-toe game.

Comment: -1: What is the point of passing execution form button*_click to method handleButtonCLick to choose which button was clicked and execute unique action for it ?

Comment: @Vash So any common logic between the functions can be handled in one function.. making it cleaner. If he's going to be declaring the same variables within (there's no way for me to know what his logic is) it will all be contained in a single function.

Comment: If there is any common logic it should be moved to another method. Having three methods that do same thing but are named different is the point that imho is not correct. You do not need three but one method to delegate the task. In method body you use elements that belong to object. You composition contain logic pieces that is not best practice to in this case.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most 'elegant' way to handle this situation is through the use of a Dictionary. This approach remove the need of lengthy switch statement.

First set the Tag property of every button to a unique string value using the Form Designer

```
button1.Tag = "B1"
button2.Tag = "B2"
button3.Tag = "B3"
button4.Tag = "B4"
....
```

and set the buttons click event handler to the same method

```
button1.Click = "button_click"
button2.Click = "button_click"
button3.Click = "button_click"
button4.Click = "button_click"
....
```

In code window globally declare a Dictionary inside your form

```
private Dictionary<string, Action> buttonActions;
```

Initialize the Dictionary in the Form_Load event

```
buttonActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
buttonActions.Add("B1", button1Action);
buttonActions.Add("B2", button2Action);
buttonActions.Add("B3", button3Action);
buttonActions.Add("B4", button4Action);
.....
```

Now in the button_click event handler you need to write this code

```
private void button_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
    var btnKey = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();  
    if(buttonActions.ContainsKey(btnKey))
        buttonActions[btnKey].Invoke();
}
```

of course you still need to write the specific code for each button action like

```
private void button1Action()
{ ... }
private void button2Action()
{ ... }
private void button3Action()
{ ... }
private void button4Action()
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.Net you can do this from your `Page_Load` and its equivalent in Winforms

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtons_Click);
button2.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtons_Click);
button3.Click += new EventHandler(MyButtons_Click);

protected void MyButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button clickedButton = (Button) sender;

   if(clickedButton.Text == "O")
     doThis();

   if(clickedButton.Text == "X")
      doThat();

}
```

Comment: If you are associating Click event on Page_Load event than you have to de-associate this event at Page_PreRenderComplete otherwise button click function will be called everytime page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, independently that you are using ASP.NET, WPF, Areo or WinForm. You use [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) and [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). To master this you should read a [tutorial about delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [tutorial about events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

The example will be based on C# 2.0 and WinForm.

First you have to create the method that will handle the action:

```
private void hadnleActionForButton(Button button) {

   //Do some magic after button press

}
```

When we have a method that will do the magic we need to create a event and delegate to use it, or we can just used already existing events and delegates.

In you case you wanted that action will be executed after button click

So first we create method that fits the delegate:

```
private void listener_button_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  if(sender is Button) {
    Button b = sender as Button;
    handleActionForButton(b);
  }

}
```

The last step is to assign the event to button, this is done by overloaded operator +=

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(listener_button_click);
```

And this is it.

Comment: Can I ask what the difference is between your `handeActionForButton` and what one of my suggestions was (which you downvoted)?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `Linq to Object` to create button and associate events and writing custom logic because most of the properties for this game would be same.

```
myFormConstructor()
{    
       //Panel or Container control or collection that is persistant can be used to hold buttons that will be created dynamically i.e. 9 buttons to this panel in our case
       for(int i = 1 ; i <= 9 ; i++)
       {
           var btn = new Button{
                                 Name = "btn"+i.ToString()
                                 Text = i.ToString()
                               });

           btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(listener_button_click);
           pnl.Controls.Add(btn);    
       }
}
///Write common logic for each button using if else
private void listener_button_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    var btnName = ((Button)sender).Name;
            switch (btnName)
            {
                case "btn1":
                    //handler for btn1 click
                    break;
                case "btn2":
                    //handler for btn2 click
                    break;
            }    
    }
```

EDIT: For window application, using panel/groupbox would be best option since there is a property `panel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ForEach(` that you can utilize to retrieve all buttons in panel or any container control to minimize code and write clean logic. Moreover you won't need to have any collection

Answer (score 0):

Inside your generic click handler method you can check for the name property of the calling button.

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        var btnName = ((Button)sender).Name;
        switch (btnName)
        {
            case "btn1":
                //handler for btn1 click
                break;
            case "btn2":
                //handler for btn2 click
                break;
        }
}
```