# Validating Textboxs

Tags: vb.net, winforms, isnumeric

I am doing a simple aplication using Windows Forms and I have a question...

My form has 15 textboxs and I want to validate everyone using the event KeyPress or validating. I have this code that is working:

```
If Not IsNumeric(txtn1.Text) Then
e.Cancel = True
ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtn1, "")
Else
something(txtn1.text)
End If
```

But I have 15 textboxs (maybe more) and is a little humdrum copy/pase this code in every textbox event. Can you teach me to do this using a function?

```
Public Function isnum(ByVal txt As TextBox, ByVal errpro as ErrorProvider) As Double
If Not IsNumeric(txt.Text) Then
e.Cancel = True    <-------------------------------This dont work
errpro.SetError(txt, "")
End If    
End Function


Private Sub txtn1_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtKLDC.Validating

if isnum(txtn1, ErrorProvider1) then
something(txtn1.text)
end if
```

I´m looking for the correct way to do this?

*English is my second language and I'm learning programming too.*

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659844/how-do-you-figure-out-if-any-of-the-buttons-was-clicked-in-c/12659909#12659909. It is essentially the same as what you're asking. You hook up each textbox to the same event handler (the example I provided uses buttons.. but its the same principle).

Answer (score 1):

Use a common KeyPress event then use the sender object which is the TextBox that originated the Event and cast it to a TextBox.

```
Private Sub txt_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtn1.KeyPress, txtn2.KeyPress, txtn3.KeyPress, txtn4.KeyPress, txtn5.KeyPress
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If Not IsNumeric(tb.Text) Then
        e.Handled = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(tb, "")
    Else
        something(tb.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! That's what I was looking for

Comment: @user1342394 Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
Private Sub NumericValidation_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) _
Handles TextBox1.KeyPress, TextBox2.KeyPress, upto 16500 or so is possible...

Dim txt As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
If Not IsNumeric(txt.Text) Then
e.Cancel = True
ErrorProvider1.SetError(txt, "")
Else
something(txt.text)
End If
End Sub
```

Notice how I assign each one of the Textbox's KeyPress Event Handler to the single NumericValidation_KeyPress sub routine. I cast the sender into a Textbox to find out which textbox keypress event fired.

Comment: Why Dim tb? You do not use that variable

Comment: lol, you tagged your question C# and VB.Net and I used c# syntax initially - you can see the edit history. Then reviewing Marks answer I changed it - looks like your good enough to spot the problems youself now:)